# Portrait app. Landscape video. shouldAutoRotate not running

Tags: ios, orientation, ios7

I have a really annoying problem that I've been fighting with for hours now. I have an app that runs in portrait only, but when I play video I want that to playback in landscape.

From what I've read the way around this is to change the Info.plist to allow landscape right, left and portrait, then to go through all the viewControllers and put in the following code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

//ios4 and ios5
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

The problem is that it appears that this isn't getting called at all as free rotation is still allowed when running the app.

Can anyone think of something that could possibly be causing this problem?

I don't know if it's worth mentioning, but I am running the latest beta of xcode 5 and running ios 7 on my iPhone 5.

Thanks a lot.
Luke

Comment: did you got solution?? also had same problem today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. In my case, I wanted all my app to be in Portrait, except 1 UINavigationController. This is how I solved it:

I have an App with a UItabBarController as root. Each of my 5 tabs are embedded in a UINavigationController… and that seems to be the problem. So, what I did was

1- You have to allow all "Device Orientations" in your "Deployment Info"

2- I created a custom class for my UITabBarController.

3- In the .m of that I added the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; }
```

4- Then, in the UIViewController I wanted to be different I added the following code in .m:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES; }

 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; }
```

Et voilà !

Hope this helps.

Konrad